# Limiting sudo permissions of a user within a group that has broader permissions

Tags: sudo

Long story short, the `admins` group is used for SSH authentication and for determining sudoers permissions. All members of the `admins` group should have unlimited sudo access, except for `jsmith`. `jsmith` needs to authenticate just like the other members of `admins`, but should only have sudo permission to run `systemctl restart smithscoolapp`.

I tried editing sudoers to look like this:

```
jsmith ALL=systemctl restart smithscoolapp
admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

However, `jsmith` is still able to sudo into commands other than `systemctl restart smithscoolapp`. Is it possible to set sudoer permissions for a specific member of a group, or should I create a "subadmins" group specifically for this user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `!ALL` for the user.

eg I have this configuration:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
sweh ALL=(ALL) !ALL,/bin/ls
```

My user is in the `wheel` group.  So if I ask for what commands I can run:

```
$ sudo -l 
User sweh may run the following commands on test1:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) !ALL, /bin/ls
```

So now I can just run the `ls` command, but not `cat`.

```
$ sudo ls /root
anaconda-ks.cfg  ks-post.log  original-ks.cfg

$ sudo cat /etc/shadow
Sorry, user sweh is not allowed to execute '/bin/cat /etc/shadow' as root on test1.
```

Comment: You need to make sure the restriction comes after the allowance command. The `sudoers` manual specifies that the last match made to a user is the one that is used.

Comment: Yes, definitely, order matters.  `sudo` will go through the rules in order and the last one that matches the command for the calling user will be the one that's applied.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can remove permissions in the way that you describe.

You should instead separate out the permissions for `ssh` and for `sudo` into two separate groups. Assign all your users to the new `ssh` group, and add all but `jsmith` to the `sudo` group.

Remember that on UNIX/Linux systems, groups are neither hierarchical nor inherited. You must include all chosen users each group.